# Regex expression to allow alphabets, numbers and new line

Tags: php, regex

I want to allow only alphabets, number NEW LINE and .:,?"()-_ characters. All are find but I am not getting where to add the new line code. Please correct my below code.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z .:,?"()-_]{30,1000}\r?\n$/', $sendermessage)
{
echo error....
}
```

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `\r\n` inside your character group (and remove it from anywhere else if it is not needed there!):

```
[0-9a-zA-Z .:,?"()-_\r\n]
```

If you can use only `\n` (without `\r`) depends on your platform.
[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is some more explanation on character groups.

Your whole regex should look like this:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z .:,?"()-_\r\n]{30,1000}$/
```

Comment: Thanks dear... i was using \n before but not \r. Thanks you its working fine.. i cannot accept ur answer before 9 minutes.. I will do it..

Comment: If you have a hyphen - in the character class [...], either escape it \- or put it at the very end, so it's not misinterpreted as a _range_. You might also need to use the "s" flag on the pattern (`"/.../s"`) to have it look at newlines too.